# com.sun.messaging cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, message-queue

While I'm trying to instantiate ConnectionFactory with:

```
ConnectionFactory connFac = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
```

It gives `"com.sun.messaging cannot be resolved to a type"` error. I'm using Eclipse EE Luna IDE with JDK 1.8u25.

Comment: Using the `sun` package is [discouraged](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) even by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I had to include the  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloadimq42jar.htm file that I thought was already inbuilt with J2EE Eclipse. In no tutorial is this thing mentioned.

Comment: If I do that, the compiler finds the missing classes, but I get a NoClassDefFoundError. Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your Project name.
2. Click *Properties*.
3. Click *Java Build Path*.
4. Click *Add Class Folder*.
5. Select your class.
6. Save
7. Restart Eclipse